# Create a new list from two separate sets of columns - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two lists of data. Both are name lists. First name and Last name are columns in each sheet. I want to create a new list from the matches of both lists. Essentially, the list needs to have all the matches from both sheets.

```
Column A - Last Name(1st data set)
Column B - First Name(1st data set)

Column C - Last Name(2nd data set)
Column D - First Name(2nd data set)
```

Answer (score 0):

In column E enter formula:

> =IF(AND(A1=C1; B1=D1); A1 & " " & B1;"")

Use auto-fill to fill all rows in column E and filter out all blanks in column E.

Use EXACT if you need case-sensitive comparison:

> =IF(AND(EXACT(A1,C1);EXACT(B1,D1)); A1 & " " & B1;"")

You can find more details [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/08/26/excel-compare-two-columns-matches-differences/)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work, I believe I need to use INDEX MATCH

Comment: Oh, misunderstood you question. You are correct, you can use VLOOKUP or INDEX MATCH for that